# Summing two seperate queries into one value using UNION ALL clause

Tags: sql, subquery, union

I have the following query (as part of a larger query). I am trying to get the sum results from 2 different data sets within a subquery but I am having trouble trying to encapsulate the two into 1 value. What I have is this:

```
(Select SUM('Invoiced MTD') from 

    ((Select SUM(CASE WHEN SOH.LASDLVNUM_0 <> '' AND SOH.LASINVNUM_0 <> '' AND MONTH(SOH.SHIDAT_0) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 
    (SOP.NETPRI_0 * SOQ.QTY_0 * SOH.CHGRAT_0) ELSE 0 END) as 'Invoiced MTD' 
    From x3v6.CICPROD.SORDER SOH
    LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.BPCUSTOMER BPC on SOH.BPCORD_0 = BPC.BPCNUM_0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.SORDERQ SOQ on SOH.SOHNUM_0 = SOQ.SOHNUM_0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.SORDERP SOP on SOQ.SOHNUM_0 = SOP.SOHNUM_0 and SOQ.SOPLIN_0 = SOP.SOPLIN_0 and SOQ.SOQSEQ_0 = SOP.SOPSEQ_0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.ITMMASTER ITM on SOP.ITMREF_0 = ITM.ITMREF_0 ))

    UNION ALL

    ((Select SUM(CASE WHEN SIH.INVTYP_0 = 2 and MONTH(SIH.ACCDAT_0) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN SID.AMTNOTLIN_0 * (-1) ELSE 0 END) as 'Invoiced MTD'
    From x3v6.CICPROD.SINVOICE SIH 
    Left Outer Join x3v6.CICPROD.SINVOICED SID on SIH.NUM_0 = SID.NUM_0))

 as 'T2',
```

But I am getting an error where the UNION ALL clauses is, and I can't figure it out. Basically I want to combine Sales credit memos with the sales order dollar totals from a seperate table.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Do the data types for your two columns match?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `sum()` over a string literal doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: DMBS is SQL-SRV 2012 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
Select SUM([Invoiced MTD]) from
(  
  Select SUM(CASE WHEN SOH.LASDLVNUM_0 <> '' AND SOH.LASINVNUM_0 <> '' AND MONTH(SOH.SHIDAT_0) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
                   THEN (SOP.NETPRI_0 * SOQ.QTY_0 * SOH.CHGRAT_0) ELSE 0 END) as 'Invoiced MTD' 
   From x3v6.CICPROD.SORDER SOH
   LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.BPCUSTOMER BPC on SOH.BPCORD_0 = BPC.BPCNUM_0
   LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.SORDERQ SOQ on SOH.SOHNUM_0 = SOQ.SOHNUM_0
   LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.SORDERP SOP on SOQ.SOHNUM_0 = SOP.SOHNUM_0 and SOQ.SOPLIN_0 = SOP.SOPLIN_0 and SOQ.SOQSEQ_0 = SOP.SOPSEQ_0
   LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPROD.ITMMASTER ITM on SOP.ITMREF_0 = ITM.ITMREF_0 

UNION ALL
   Select SUM(CASE WHEN SIH.INVTYP_0 = 2 and MONTH(SIH.ACCDAT_0) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
                THEN SID.AMTNOTLIN_0 * (-1) ELSE 0 END) as 'Invoiced MTD'
   From x3v6.CICPROD.SINVOICE SIH 
   Left Outer Join x3v6.CICPROD.SINVOICED SID on SIH.NUM_0 = SID.NUM_0
)T
```

Comment: I tried to post the entire query, but can't due to its length. If someone can provide me with their e-mail or a way to post it I would because it would help troubleshoot this error. The error is incorrect syntax near "UNION" and incorrect syntax near ')'. Thank you

Comment: this worked, I just need to group the subquery now as this displays the overall totals.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  I'm not sure exactly what is causing your issue, but you definitely don't need so many parenthesis.  I would also recommend using something that formats/ beautifies your SQL.  It's a great way to 1) keep your code looking consistent and 2) flesh out syntax errors.

```
SELECT SUM(x.invoiced_mtd)
  FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE
                     WHEN soh.lasdlvnum_0 <> '' AND soh.lasinvnum_0 <> '' AND
                          MONTH(soh.shidat_0) = MONTH(getdate()) THEN
                      (sop.netpri_0 * soq.qty_0 * soh.chgrat_0)
                     ELSE
                      0
                   END) AS invoiced_mtd
          FROM x3v6.cicprod.sorder soh
          LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.cicprod.bpcustomer bpc
            ON soh.bpcord_0 = bpc.bpcnum_0
          LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.cicprod.sorderq soq
            ON soh.sohnum_0 = soq.sohnum_0
          LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.cicprod.sorderp sop
            ON soq.sohnum_0 = sop.sohnum_0
           AND soq.soplin_0 = sop.soplin_0
           AND soq.soqseq_0 = sop.sopseq_0
          LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.cicprod.itmmaster itm
            ON sop.itmref_0 = itm.itmref_0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SUM(CASE
                     WHEN sih.invtyp_0 = 2 AND
                          MONTH(sih.accdat_0) = MONTH(getdate()) THEN
                      sid.amtnotlin_0 * (-1)
                     ELSE
                      0
                   END)
          FROM x3v6.cicprod.sinvoice sih
          LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.cicprod.sinvoiced sid
            ON sih.num_0 = sid.num_0) x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone. I probably should have included the full context of the query. Here it is:

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CTE for the `UNION` query first.  Here is a simplified example with the same structure as your query:

```
;with cteTest AS (

    ((select 2 as 'test'))
    union all
    ((select 3 as 'test'))

)

select sum(test) from cteTest
```